# Canon Printer - Strange issue on Mac (ccpd wants to connect to the internet)

Tags: macos, printer

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite and my native firewall is active. Whenever I restart/open my computer, I see a messagebox that asks me whether I want to allow ccpd to connect to the internet or not.

I installed a fresh copy of Yosemite in order to understand what's going on, but I get the same message every time.

Virustotal : https://www.virustotal.com/tr/file/519c2fe540b1fa0807b0ff330eb02dc956b62387da20f18cb57089ceff52b971/analysis/1415748397/
(It says the exact file with the same hash has been scanned before and found no malware, so I think my computer isn't infected.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI4gB.png

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same to me. It's exactly an error by Canon Printer driver for my LBP2900 printer.

**This fixed for me:**
- Go to Library/Preferences and DELETE this file: *com.apple.alf.plist*
- Restart my MAC and DONE!!!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) would be even better if you edit and expand it with an explanation as to *why* your solution fixes/addresses the OPs question.

Comment: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist` appears to be the system _application firewall_ configuration. Deleting it seems to remove all the firewall rules and disable the firewall. Reenabling the firewall again brings back all the previous problems. This is not a fix but a rather dangerous workaround.